# Can we create generic MongoRepository for all Documents in spring

Tags: spring, mongodb

I wants to create Generic MongoRepository for all Document objects. Instead of having like MongoRepository for each individual document object , I want MongoRepository for all document objects. Here all document objects are extending Entity. Needs to create separate collection for all documents in database based on persisting Objects.

Comment: Sorry, I don't totally understand your question. What have you tried? And, why do you want them all in one collection? For indexing, it's better to have different types of documents with unique indexing requirements in separate collections.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
Actually i am trying to create two projects 
1. first project having generic services ,repository and base model.  
2. second project make use of above services and child models extending base model.

I need to create generic repository in first project using base model. It has to save child models data with respective child model collection names.